# Add seed data to a Docker based Microsoft SQL Server at image build time

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

**NOTE**: I believe that this question is different than the many others that look similar.  Please read it before closing.

I am trying to build a Docker container image that has a "for testing" copy of my database.  I have a script that will create this.  It takes about 60 seconds to run.

I put this into a docker container by following the steps outline by Julie Lerman [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/july/data-points-on-the-fly-sql-servers-with-docker).  It worked just fine **except that it runs my script when the container instance is created**.  This means that I have to wait 60 seconds before the database is fully ready.

I want to incur the 60 second cost when the image is built, not when the container starts up (startup is when my automated tests need it to be ready fast!)

**How can I create a Sql Server container image that has my database script pre-run?**

NOTE: I need this to be a repeatable, auto-build process.  As such I am hesitant to use `docker commit`

Answer (score 1):

This command ended up doing it:

```
RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && /createScript.sh
```

`createScript.sh` is a bash script that calls SqlCmd on the sql script you want to run.

The key is to do a RUN, so it is done at image build time.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/229